# Ganymed - how to execute ssh/scp that requires a password

Tags: java

I use [Ganymed](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/),  which is a library that implements the SSH-2 protocol, and I want it to connect to other sever and copy to other sever files.

The problem is that the `ssh` and `scp` commands requires a password (I cant do it with keys) and as I do it - it doesnt work.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String username = "sabre";
    String host = "beta";
    String password = "xxxxxxxx";

    try
    {
        Connection conn = new Connection(host);
        conn.connect();
        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (!isAuthenticated)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

        sess.requestPTY("bash");
        sess.startShell();

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new new  OutputStreamWriter(sess.getStdin(), "utf-8");
        writer.write("ssh nir@192.168.1.123 \n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.write("password\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        sess.waitForCondition(ChannelCondition.CLOSED | ChannelCondition.EOF | ChannelCondition.EXIT_STATUS, 10000);

        sess.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
```

When I debug this I see that the server return that the access is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `Ganymed` but just by looking at the code I suspect that you send password too early. You probably need to handle what server responds to you. In other words server receives not what you think it receives.

Comment: I can wait until the server wait for the password and then I'll enter the `password`. Is that what you meant? or you saying that there is probably different method to send responds to the server?

Comment: @nir Yep. Try waiting for response and then send password.